# Does clang support a double-word-compare-and-exchange operation?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have been reading through and coding up examples from Anthony Williams' book [Concurrency in Practice](http://www.manning.com/williams/) and needed to enable double-word-compare-and-exchange for gcc4.8 using `-mcx16` so that a struct containing a pointer an int could be manipulated in a lock-free atomic manner.

Does Clang (any version) support double-word-compare-and-exchange on x64?

The following code gives linking errors in GCC4.8 and Clang 3.3 without extra compiler options:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

struct ReferenceCountedPointer
{
  int referenceCount;
  void* data;
};

int main()
{
  std::atomic<ReferenceCountedPointer> arcp;
  ReferenceCountedPointer rcp;

  arcp.compare_exchange_weak(rcp, rcp);

  return 0;
}
```

The above program is pointless but illustrates the linking errors I see.

Compilation commands I used for Clang and GCC are:

Clang 3.3:

```
clang++-mp-3.3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ CX16.cpp -o CX16
```

Fails with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___atomic_compare_exchange", referenced from:
  _main in CX16-plVSvq.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

GCC4.8:

```
g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 CX16.cpp -o CX16
```

Fails with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___atomic_compare_exchange_16", referenced from:
  std::atomic<ReferenceCountedPointer>::compare_exchange_weak(ReferenceCountedPointer&,        ReferenceCountedPointer, std::memory_order, std::memory_order) in ccOjp95s.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Most systems provide this kind of stuff. Why do you want/need to rely on a compiler feature?

Comment: You can always use inline assembler

Comment: @Macmade neither GCC 4.8 nor Clang 3.3 will link my code without the flag. I'll update the question with a minimal code sample

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't think I need to. Would be nice to keep things portable.

Comment: @jcoe: portable is relative here if you are already tied to a specific processor model (range).

Comment: this is obviously a bug in both libraries (llvm's libc++ and gnu's libstdc++), as they seem to declare a method which cannot be resolved at loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReferenceCountedPointer` is trivially copyable, so the code is valid under C++11. Apparently the library does not conform to the standard.

Comment: It looks like libc++ and libstdc++ are falling short. Both complain about missing symbols.

Comment: I was under the impression that my code would compile and link even without double-word-compare-exchange but would use mutexes and not be lock free. This seems consistent with what you say.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say. To compare and exchange a data structure that has one pointer and one integer, in a 64-bit architecture, requires a 16-byte compare-exchange operation - if not, then it's not going to be atomic. Of course, one could write some "mutex" locks or similar around it, but I don't think that satisfies the technical definition of atomic. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Perhaps I am confused but I thought that atomic<> for user defined-types would be implemented with a mutex by the compiler when double-word operations were not supported by the platform. Even without double-word operations compare-exchange can be made atomic by using a mutex, but not lock-free-atomic. I'm keen to find out what clang's cx16 flag is if it exists. Why the code fails to link might be better as another question if it should be legal c++11.

Comment: @jcoe - the only atomic type that is **required** to be lock free is `std::atomic_flag`. The others may or may not be, which is why there are the `...is_lock_free` functions and the `ATOMIC...LOCK_FREE` macros. Of course, if `T` in `std::atomic<T>` is small enough, any decent implementation will generate lock-free code; typically that's done for integral types. Microsoft's implementation (which I wrote) makes `atomic<T>` lock-free for **any** `T` that's small enough to be handled without a mutex.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - for every type `T` that's trivially copyable (integer types and appropriate UDTs), `atomic<T>` is atomic. For types that are too large to be handled without a lock (mutex or otherwise), the implementation uses a lock; operations on those types are not lock free, but they're still atomic.

Comment: @jcoe - just so it doesn't get lost in the weeds, when `T` is too large to be handled by the processor's atomic operations, but is still trivially copyable, the implementation uses some kind of lock (mutex or whatever) and `memcmp` and `memcpy` to implement the atomic operations for `atomic<T>`.

Comment: To clarify: "atomic" in the C++11 atomic types means that operations from multiple threads do not create data races, that caches get updated, and that the compiler won't move reads or writes across an atomic operation. That's the abstraction. Processor-level notions such as 16-byte compare-exchange operations are implementation details; if they're available, they should be used; regardless, the implementation has to provide the correct semantics, and its the semantics that you program to, not the implementation details.

Comment: It looks like GCC4.8 and Clang 3.3 are failing to provide a mutex-based fallback in the absence of primitive operations. Given that this question was initially about a flag for Clang I've asked why the linking errors occur here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437983/missing-atomic-compare-exchange-why-does-code-compile-then-fail-to-link

Comment: Clang 3.4 with Xcode 5.0 libc++ has no problem. As reported above this looks like a library short-coming and thankfully a temporary one.

I've been abysmally slow in accepting Pete Becker's answer. Apologies and thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that SOME models of 64-bit processors do not have a `cmpxchg16b`. The `-mcx16` tells the compiler that "I know that this processor supports the cmpxchg16b instructions, so you can generate it". This is to avoid problems with older 64-bit processors which don't support this instruction - they would then cause an "illegal opcode trap". It's the same thing as using for example SSE4.